# Show that functional is bounded linear

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\displaystyle\mathcal{H}=H^1(\Omega)$ with $\displaystyle \langle u,v\rangle_{1,2}=\int_\Omega \left (\nabla u \cdot \nabla v +uv\right ) \mathrm{d}x $

We can then define $l\in\mathcal{H}^*$ by $\displaystyle l(v):=\int_\Omega fv\,\mathrm{d}x$

as $\displaystyle |l(v)|\le \|f\|_2\|u\|_2\le \|f\|_2\|u\|_{1,2}$

I don't understand how this estimate was done. I would normally consider

$\displaystyle \|l\| =\sup_{v\in\mathcal{H},\ \|v\|_{1,2}=1} \left | l(v)\right |$

and show that this is finite. How do I know that the supremum even exists in the estimate above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the estimate should be written as
$$|l(v)|\le \|f\|_2\|v\|_2\le \|f\|_2\|v\|_{1,2}.$$

Using the estimate, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\|l\|
 &= \sup_{v\in \mathcal H, \|v\|_{1,2}=1} |l(v) | \\
&\leq
\sup_{v\in \mathcal H, \|v\|_{1,2}=1} \|f\|_2 \|v\|_{1,2} \\ 
&\leq
\| f\|_2.
\end{align}
$$

Now we know that $\|l\|$ is finite.